# Android multiple spinners different ID's

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I would like to create multiple spinners in an app, all of which have the values 0 to 60

I currently am using the following code to populate on spinner (from 140 to 160). Which is working great. Now i need to add 5 spinners all of which have the options of 0 to 60.

What would be the best way to create multiple spinners, and populate them, with different ID's (spinner1, spinner2, spinner3 etc...)

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modesrangespinner);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=140; i<=160; i++){
            String num = String.valueOf(i);
            list.add(num);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your further use of your spinners. But you have your answer with in your code, like this,

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner() {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<=60; i++){
        String num = String.valueOf(i);
        list.add(num);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modesrangespinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modesrangespinner2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modesrangespinner3);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modesrangespinner4);
    spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modesrangespinner5);

    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner3.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner4.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner5.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a id is a integer, so if you give the ids like this:

```
R.id.spinner1
R.id.spinner2
R.id.spinner3
R.id.spinner4
R.id.spinner5
```

You can initialize all of them like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<=60; i++){
    String num = String.valueOf(i);
    list.add(num);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Spinner spinner;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1 + i);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```